# Wordpress custom theme "Read More"

Tags: wordpress

I'm building my first custom theme in Wordpress using Bootstrap 5.
My problem is I can't understand how display "Read More" button on the bottom of the post.
I tried many ways like:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="r_more" target="_blank">Read More...</a>';
```

But nothing happen.

How could I add "Read more" link following best practise?

Comment: try to view source and see what is actually echo-ed. also, how can it be that nothing happens? maybe there's error in the developers console? also, doesn't the `get_permalink` expects a `post_id` as parameter? since you are probably attempting to link from an "index" page, there are as many post_id's as the number of posts. so you need to be specific.

Comment: I didn't notice get_permalink was empty.
I just adde post like this: get_permalink( 'post' )
and now it is working. is this a correct way to display "red more"? Or should I  create a function to di it? @ITgoldman

Comment: ```function read_more ( $excerpt ){
    $post = get_post();
    $excerpt .= '<a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" class="apc-more-link">' . 
    esc_html__( 'Read More', 'apc' ) . '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>';
    return $excerpt;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'read_more ', 21 );```

Comment: At the end i just changed something: echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="apc-more-link">' . esc_html__( 'Read More', 'apc' ) . '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>';